# Combinatorics-graph colouring

Tags: combinatorics

Show that if $K_9 $is coloured red and blue and contains no red triangle and no blue $K_4$, then every vertex must have red degree $3$ and blue degree $5$.

I have absolutely no idea how to proceed :(

Comment: It's not a duplicate since the other person asked about the second part of the question, whereas I'm stuck on the first part.

Comment: It is a duplicate, the first part is the key.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a vertex $v$ with red degree at least $4$. Choose any $4$ of the "red" neighbours of $v$. Can any of the edges between these four vertices be red? But can they *all* be blue?

On the other hand, suppose you have a vertex with blue degree at least $6$. Choose any $6$ of these "blue" neighbours. Note that these form a $K_6$ subgraph with edges coloured red and blue. Can there be a red triangle? Can there be a blue triangle? The answer is no to both, and why is this a contradiction?

Comment: But there MUST be a red triangle or a blue K_4 by one of the theorems. I'm confused.

Comment: @Richard Which theorem do you have in mind?

Comment: I don't think it had a name but I'm sure I read it somewhere.

Comment: @richard I suspect it is the one you are trying to prove here.

Comment: Oh right, thanks. I'm confused by your method though. Could you please explain it more clearly to me. Many Thanks, I appreciate your replies. :)

Comment: @Richard The ideas I'm hinting at are similar to the ideas used in the proof that every colouring of the edges of $K_6$ with red and blue must have a red or blue triangle. [See here for an explanation](http://youtu.be/Ya2IFgRDbo4?t=25m8s).

Comment: Why can't there be a red or blue triangle?

Comment: @Richard Watch the first few minutes of the video I linked to.